# Jquery mobile beginner

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have a small web-application, that I want to convert to use jquery mobile.
But although I think I have all the beginner docs I have some problems
The following page STILL shows the "native" select-dropdown box, as far as I can tell
Can anyone spot the problem quickly..?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/[version]/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Hello world</p>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <label for="select-custom-1">Basic:</label>
            <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
                <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
                <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
                <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>My Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Replace 1.4.5 with [version] on line 6 where you import the stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here. Firstly `[version]` in the URL should be the actual version string of the jQuery mobile instance you're using; `1.4.5` in this case.

Secondly, jQuery 3.x doesn't support jQuery Mobile. You'll need to use an older version, such as 1.12.1:

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="select-custom-1">Basic:</label>
        <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
          <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
          <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
          <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
          <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>My Footer</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks guys!
The version thing is of course plain stupid. I must have been fiddling so much that I forgot that in the end. The version thing is quite new to me. Where can I read more about that?
Anyway, thanks

Comment: Which 'version thing' do you mean? The URL or the lack of support in 3.x?